# How to filter google links while scraping with python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, scraper

I’m taking the names and addresses of certain companies and using requests and beautiful soup to query google and scrape the yelp link that corresponds with the business. I currently have it set up where it takes the first link google offers, but sometimes it’s not the correct one. Instead of grabbing the first link google gives me, how do I go about grabbing multiple links and filtering through them to make sure it’s the right one?

Here's my code:

```
yelps = []

for i in range(0,len(orders)):
    print orders[i][0]
    #orders[i][1] = name
    #orders[i][2] = address
    #orders[i][3] = city, state
    research_later = orders[i][1] + orders[i][2] + orders[i][3]
    goog_search = "https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-  instant&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS667US667&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=yelp+" + research_later
    print goog_search
    try:
        r = requests.get(goog_search)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
        yelps.append(soup.find('cite').text)
        print soup.find('cite').text
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print e
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Why are you using Google to search for Yelp links instead of just searching on Yelp directly? That would solve your first problem.

As for the second one, you can do `cite = soup.find('cite').text` and then`if cite != None:yelps.append(cite)` instead of `yelps.append(soup.find('cite').text)`.

Comment: Yelp's search engine is not good and would make it even harder to code. And when I try cite = soup.find('cite').text and if cite != None:yelps.append(cite) I get an error: yelps.append(soup.find('cite').text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: please add `orders` object example